# System.Uri.ToString() unescapes uriencoded querystrings. How to stop it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I do:

```
new Uri("http://www.example.com?name=i%20hate%20asp.net!").ToString()
```

it doesn't return:

```
http://www.example.com?name=i%20hate%20asp.net!
```

it returns:

```
http://www.example.com?name=i hate asp.net!
```

Why? How do I make this work correctly?

Comment: Why do you care? Give the bigger picture and maybe there's better way or at least work around.

Comment: why do i care? because its not RFC compliant. consider: `http://www.mydomain.com?key=http://www.ietf.org:80` totally invalid and/or will give unexpected behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`Uri.AbsoluteUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). `ToString()` is just a string representation of the underlying data, not a proper URI.

```
new Uri("http://www.mydomain.com?name=i%20hate%20asp.net!").AbsoluteUri
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this behaviour may be absolutely correct, the ToString()-Method is intended to show human readable results.
The Specification for this method says:

```
(via http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx)

Return Value
Type: System.String
A String instance that contains the unescaped canonical representation of the Uri instance. All characters are unescaped except #, ?, and %.
```

What is your intend with the string representation of the uri? maybe with that information, we can provide the correct solution for youtr problem. I suppose you need to use yourUri.AbsoluteUri instead of yourUri.ToString() in the general case.

Comment: Agreed. Wouldn't have expected that behviour though

Comment: me too, I had my lessons learned some time ago with this. now the Static analysis alert "use System.Uri instead of string" makes much more sense, especially when the code causing this calls something like `new WebRequest(uri.ToString())`...